# Can I find the marginal distribution by fitting a distribution to the event dimension, rather than integrating over the variables?

Tags: marginal-distribution

I have a 6-dimensional data which I fitted with a 6-dimensional Gaussian mixture model and I would like to obtain the marginal distribution of all 1-dimensional events. However, I find it difficult to perform integration over the irrelevant variables in a high dimensional mixture model.

This is why, since I have the full data, I assumed I could fit a 1-d mixture model to the desired event dimension, and have the same outcome as performing the integration.

Marginal distribution [gives the probabilities of various values of the variables in the subset without reference to the values of the other variables.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution)
Then, how can I define the univariate distribution fitted to the variable of interest? Does that distribution have reference to other variable?
**Or** Is a fitted univariate distribution (fitted to the 1-d data exclusively) and the marginal distribution of the variables the same thing?